# Install Mercurial Eclipse on 22.04 in Eclipse 4.24?

Tags: 22.04, eclipse, mercurial

Has anyone found a way to install mercurial eclipse on 22.04? I believe i used the eclipse market place drag in my older 18.04 version of eclipse but it does not seem to work on the current version of eclipse 2022-06 (4.24.0).

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mercurialeclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you linked to seems to be pretty out of date - last update in Feb 2019 it seems.

But there is a comment on that page which states:

> *Submitted by Marc Guenther on Mon, 2020-09-21 11:42*
>
> The marketplace version has been broken for over a year now.
>
> After Bitbucket destruction by Atlassian, the new home of the plugin
> is: https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/mercurialeclipse/-/wikis/home

And indeed if you visit the [Heptapod page](https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/mercurialeclipse/-/wikis/home) it seems to be much more recent, with a release in the last 4 months or so. I have not actually tried this release myself but it seems like a better starting point.

Note that Heptapod has become the home of other Mercurial-related tools as well, such as [TortoiseHG](https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/tortoisehg/thg) and maybe even [Mercurial itself](https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/mercurial-devel).